# Function Return object

Tags: php, oop

I was following a tutorial that I got a problem

```
function old($field) {
    return request($field);
}

function request($field = null) {
    $request = new \App\Helper\Request();
    if(is_null($field))
        return $request;
        return $request->input($field);
}
```

I can't figure out why we should set $filed as null and what happens while using two return?the usage of old function is keeping true values after validation in register menu textboxes

the following source code is request class which manages the requests:

```
class Request
{
public function input($filed, $post = true)
{
if ($this->isPost() && $post)
        return isset($_POST[$filed]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST[$filed]) : "";

    return isset($_GET[$filed]) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET[$filed]) : "";
}


public function all($post = true)
{
    if ($this->isPost() && $post)
        return isset($_POST) ? array_map('htmlspecialchars' , $_POST) : null;

    return isset($_GET) ?array_map('htmlspecialchars' , $_GET) : null;
}


public function isPost()
{
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST';
}
}
```

PS:if someone needs more information, please tell me I will send the complete source code.
Thank you

Comment: When you'll learn to indent your code and how to place `{}` you will understand that these are two `return`s for different cases. One is when `field` is null and second - when `field` is __not__ null.

Comment: Setting the field as null allows you to say *I want the whole request* by saying `request()` or an individual field `request('id')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i can't figure out why we should set $field as null and what happens while using two return?

You are not setting `$field` to null but `$field` here is an optional argument that means, if no argument is passed to the function, `null` will be used as default value.

And then this:

```html
$request = new \App\Helper\Request();

if(is_null($field))
    return $request;
return $request->input($field);
```

simply means, if `$field` is `null` then return the result of `new \App\Helper\Request()` otherwise the result of `$request->input($field)` where `$request=new \App\Helper\Request()`

Even if I may have just one single line instruction inside if statement, I prefer to use parenthesis for more readability and best understanding.